# How to extract the fields (Country, State, ... E-mail) from a p12 file without password

Tags: security, certificate, key, public-key-encryption, private-key

I have a file.p12 which contains the private key protected  with a password (that i have not) and the public certificate.

I have tried the following commands in the cmd of windows:

```
pkcs12 -in file.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out publicCert.pe
```

But it require the private passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can't.

While a PFX supports many different configurations, the default is to encrypt the private keys with 3DES-CBC and the certificates with RC2/40-CBC; each encrypted segment uses the password as input into a formula to produce a different cryptographic key.

So your two easiest options are to know the password, or to try to crack the RC2 payloads.